# How would I find the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+x+2}{(x+1)(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

The goal is to find this integral: $$\int_0^1\frac{x^2+x+2}{(x+1)(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
I have been on this question for a long time and I am halfway through solving it:
[image]

As shown above, using partial fraction decomposition with two linear factors, I have found that $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+x+2}{(x+1)(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Where do I go from here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: These are standard integrals I would think you are familiar with.  $\int \frac{dx}{1+x}=\log(1+x)$ and $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan x$

Comment: @saulspatz i didnt know this thank you but what do I do from there?

Comment: The expression $x^2+x+2/(x+1)(1+x^2)$ means the same thing as $x^2+x+ \dfrac 2{(x+1)(1+x^2)}$ but your hand-written page says $\dfrac{x^2+x+2}{(x+1)(1+x^2)}. \qquad$

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan 1 - \arctan0 = \frac\pi4 - 0.
$$
$$ {} $$
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x} = \log_e(1+1) - \log_e(1+0) = (\log_e2) - 0
$$ $${}$$

Comment: @Michael Hardy this helped a lot thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\int \frac{1}{x+1} \, dx$ you should spot that since the derivative of $\log|x|$ is $1/x$, the derivative of $\log|x+1|$ is
$$
\frac{1}{x+1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x+1)=\frac{1}{x+1}\cdot 1 = \frac{1}{x+1}
$$
using the chain rule. Hence,
$$
\int \frac{1}{x+1} \, dx = \log\left|x+1\right|+C \, ,
$$
and you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to find the definite integral. For $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx$, it helps to simply know that the derivative of $\arctan x$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Failing that, you can make the substitution $x=\tan\theta$. If you do make this substitution, remember to change the integral bounds.

Comment: thank you very much! i understand this part now but howdo we get to  to pi/4 +ln2?

Comment: @maryjames: Which part are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: wait i looked at it again and understood it thank you very much